# Twitter+OAuth Crash on iPhone OS 2.x

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth, exc-bad-access

I'm using Ben Gottlieb's [Twitter+OAuth](http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) code.

Works great on my 3.1.2 iPhone, but crashes on my 2.2.1 iPhone. I'm getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in the `EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize` call. Here's what I'm seeing in the debugger:

```
#0  0x2fe1e724 in __dyld_pthread_getspecific
#1  0x2fe1eddc in __dyld___gthread_getspecific
#2  0x2fe1eec8 in __dyld__Unwind_SjLj_Register
#3  0x2fe07b14 in __dyld__ZN4dyld14bindLazySymbolEPK11mach_headerPm
#4  0x2fe15ebc in __dyld_stub_binding_helper_interface
#5  0x0003cab8 in EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize at Base64Transcoder.c:106
#6  0x0003cb04 in Base64EncodeData at Base64Transcoder.c:120
#7  0x0003e476 in -[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider signClearText:withSecret:] at OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider.m:50
```

What am I missing? A library that's not available with 2.2.1?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the OAuth library is being built against 3.0 frameworks. If you want to target 2.2.1, it'll need to be built against those frameworks.